# Java POS program. Discount whole total, not each price

Tags: java

I'm working on this from class. I'm trying to discount "CA Resident 5%" from the total price but I think my code is discounting each price individually then adding them. Not sure where in my program this is happening.

I'm at Basic Level java, 2nd week so I would like not to learn anything too advanced right now but to learn what my basic codes are doing wrong. Thanks

```js
import java.util.*;

public class Sept13 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

/*
========Point of Sale========
Foods           No Tax
Ciggarettes     25% Tax
Books           No Tax
Computer        10% Tax
CA Resident     5% Discount
Clothes         10 % Tax

*/




boolean CAR = false;
double total = 0, price = 0, Ca = .05, Fo, Ci = .25, Bo, Co = .10, Cl = .10;
int ans = 0;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

System.out.print("Are you a California Resident?  Type 1 if yes type 0 if no ");
  ans = in.nextInt();
      
      if (ans == 1){
         CAR = true; //Discount for California Resident
         }
         
 
//Cigarette Tax
System.out.print("Are you buying cigarettes?  Type 1 if yes type 0 if no ");
  ans = in.nextInt();
      

      
      if (ans == 1);
         System.out.print("Enter price of item(s)");
     price = in.nextDouble();
         
      if (CAR){
         total += ((price*Ci)+price);
         }
         
System.out.print(total);


//Computer Tax
System.out.print("Are you buying a computer(s)?  Type 1 if yes type 0 if no ");
  ans = in.nextInt();
      
      
      if (ans == 1);
         System.out.print("Enter price of item(s)");
     price = in.nextDouble();
         
      if (CAR){
         total += ((price*Co)+price);
         }
System.out.print(total);


//Clothes Tax   
System.out.print("Are you buying a Clothes?  Type 1 if yes type 0 if no ");
  ans = in.nextInt();
      
      
      if (ans == 1);
         System.out.print("Enter price of item(s)");
     price = in.nextDouble();
         
      if (CAR){
         total += ((price*Cl)+price);
         }
         
         

System.out.print (total-(total*Ca));


      
   

   }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are discounting each item individually after each price input before adding them to the total. If you want the discount to happen at the end, just write a single `if` statement after all inputs are in and apply the discount.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that applying discounts individually or once at the end will output the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I think this is solution for your problem.

```
//Cigarette Tax
System.out.print("Are you buying cigarettes?  Type 1 if yes type 0 if no ");

ans = in.nextInt();

if (ans == 1){
   double cigarateTax = 0;
   System.out.print("Enter price of item(s)");

   if (CAR){
         cigarateTax  += ((price*Ci)+price);
   }
   total += cigarateTax;
}
System.out.print(total);
```